# switch from input within the code to prompter?

Tags: java

This code currently takes in a date of the form dd/MM/yyyy and returns an output of month, date, year, and day on 4 separate lines. In this case, you enter the date into the code itself. But I want to make a prompter and enter the date using scanner. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to continue. The original code hasn't been changed.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Day{

    public static void main( String[] args ){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a date in the form dd/MM/yyyy:");
    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        Date myDate = newDateFormat.parse("28/12/2013");
        newDateFormat.applyPattern("EEEE dd MMM yyyy");
        String isDate = newDateFormat.format(myDate);
        String []myformat=isDate.split(" ");
        System.out.println(myformat[2]);
        System.out.println(myformat[1]);
        System.out.println(myformat[3]);
        System.out.println(myformat[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error. Date is in the wrong format.");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your S.O.p  put line 
`String date = sc.nextLine();` and modify the Date mydate line as
 `Date myDate = newDateFormat.parse(date);`. 
Final code would be

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Day{

    public static void main( String[] args ){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a date in the form dd/MM/yyyy:");
    String date = sc.nextLine();
    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        Date myDate = newDateFormat.parse(date);
        newDateFormat.applyPattern("EEEE dd MMM yyyy");
        String isDate = newDateFormat.format(myDate);
        String []myformat=isDate.split(" ");
        System.out.println(myformat[2]);
        System.out.println(myformat[1]);
        System.out.println(myformat[3]);
        System.out.println(myformat[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error. Date is in the wrong format.");
    }
    }
}
```